# Kotlin unable to infer type when using method reference in Flowable

Tags: kotlin, type-inference, rx-java2, flatmap

I have this code in Java:

```
Flowable.just(1,2,3)
        .flatMap(Flowable::just);
```

and this code in Kotlin:

```
Flowable.just(1,2,3)
        .flatMap(Flowable::just)
```

While Java code compiles fine, Kotlin compiler says: "Error:(47, 30) Kotlin: One type argument expected for class Flowable : Publisher defined in io.reactivex"

However this compiles fine:

```
Flowable.just(1,2,3)
        .flatMap { Flowable.just(it) }
```

What am I doing wrong or how come Kotlin can't infer the type of Flowable automatically?

Comment: From [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html): "A lambda expression is always surrounded by curly braces."

Answer (score 3):

This is not quite an answer, but it's too long for a comment.

In the first case that does not compile, the error has to do with Kotlin not selecting the correct `Flowable::just` method to pass to `Flowable.flatMap(...)`.  There are 10 different `Flowable.just(...)` methods defined where the difference is the number of arguments.

In the second case, you are passing `Flowable.flatMap()` a lambda that explicitly calls the single parameter version of  `Flowable.just()` (i.e., the one parameter version).

In the first case, Kotlin is apparently choosing one of the other ten `Flowable::just` methods instead of looking for one that matches the signature expected by `Flowable.flatMap()` (of which there are 12 defined).  In contrast, Java is able to deduce (from the signature of the parameter) which of the many overloads of `.just()` to pass.

This may be a Kotlin shortcoming, but I would like to hear what one of the Kotlin compiler experts have to say.